# Hide Disk read/write from System Monitor indicator

Tags: indicator, system-monitor

For some reason, my System Monitor indicator is now showing textual disk read/write speeds along the graphs:

[image: System Monitor indicator screenshot]

I cannot figure out how to remove it. When I open the preferences, only "Processor" and "Network" checkboxes are checked.

How do I remove the textual Disk read/write status from the System Monitor indicator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original reason why this appeared seems to be that I had my mouse over the indicator and then scrolled down accidentally.

From System Monitor settings, open "Indicator items", click on the empty row, and click "Down" button until that empty row sits at the bottom. That makes the textual Disk indicator disappear:

[image: Indicator items list]